# What's the best practice to scan a text file on linux for quality checking (pattern matching)?

Tags: linux, csv, hdfs

We received data from clients for processing in Hadoop, first thing is the data will arrive as a file on linus in csv format. Usually the files are good, however, we've seen cases that there are a few lines with bad data - this caused the whole processing be rejected in the last audit phase.

So it is really needed to do some data quality checking after the data arrives and before it gets ingested into the pipeline.

The data's size varies from MB to GB, thousands lines to billion+ lines.

What would be the best way to do this? Followings are current thoughts:
1. using linux command like awk or grep, ... , to filter out pattern unmatched lines;
2. writing customized python script to filter out pattern unmatched lines;

Yes, the data can also be checked in Spark, however, we think the bad data should be excluded from the pipeline at the beginning.

Your any sharing is welcome and appreciated here.

Ideally the solution can be applied onto text file on file system (Linux) as well as existing data on HDFS.

UPDATE:

Sample data below:
cat sample.txt

```
$~$TRN_FILE_DT$~$|$~$TRN_BANK_STATE_ID$~$|$~$ACCT_NUM_FULL$~$|$~$TRN_TRANSACTION_CD$~$|$~$TRN_TRANSACTION_DT$~$|$~$TRN_TRANSACTION_AMT$~$|$~$TRN_BAT_NUM$~$|$~$TRN_SEQ_NUM$~$|$~$TRN_LOCUSORTYPE$~$|$~$TRN_CITYST$~$|$~$TRN_PURPOSE$~$|$~$TRN_ATM_LOC_CD$~$|$~$TRN_AMT_LOC_ON_US$~$|$~$TRN_AMT_REMOTE_BR$~$|$~$TRN_ATM_GL_RC$~$|$~$TRN_POST_SEQ$~$|$~$TRN_POSTING_PRIORITY$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$|$~$0xBFACD988EAF6ABE515C16CE33C10F0860B33C83D$~$|$~$0129$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$1425.00$~$|$~$5912 $~$|$~$13312$~$|$~$TO CHECKING$~$|$~$$~$|$~$TO CHECKING$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00001$~$|$~$35$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$|$~$0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0170$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$3503.71$~$|$~$7200 $~$|$~$90542$~$|$~$Morgan Stanley$~$|$~$$~$|$~$ACH CREDIT$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00001$~$|$~$20$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$|$~$0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0136$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$34.00$~$|$~$8888 $~$|$~$51279$~$|$~$Village Nails & Sp$~$|$~$CRANSTON     RI$~$|$~$DBT PURCHASE$~$|$~$7230$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00001$~$|$~$35$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$||$~$001$~$||$~$0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0136$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$91.94$~$|$~$8888 $~$|$~$42283$~$|$~$AMZN Mktp US*M26ZY$~$|$~$Amzn.com/billWA$~$|$~$DBT PURCHASE$~$|$~$5942$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00002$~$|$~$35$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$|$~$0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0136$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$75.19$~$|$~$8888 $~$|$~$66089$~$|$~$P.J.'S PUB$~$|$~$NARRAGANSETT RI$~$|$~$DBT PURCHASE$~$|$~$5812$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00003$~$|$~$35$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$|$~$0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0136$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$9.34$~$|$~$8888 $~$|$~$66093$~$|$~$Amazon.com*M26TD1R$~$|$~$Amzn.com/billWA$~$|$~$DBT PURCHASE$~$|$~$5942$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00004$~$|$~$35$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$||$~$0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0135$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$57.48$~$|$~$8888 $~$|$~$42285$~$|$~$JOANN STORES #2125$~$|$~$WARWICK      RI$~$|$~$POS DEBIT$~$|$~$5949$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00005$~$|$~$35$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$|$~$|0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0135$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$7.89$~$|$~$8888 $~$|$~$42287$~$|$~$2740 SOUTH KIN$~$|$~$SOUTH KINGSTORI$~$|$~$POS DEBIT$~$|$~$5541$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00006$~$|$~$35$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$|$~$0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0136$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$5.92$~$|$~$8888 $~$|$~$66091$~$|$~$AMZN Mktp US*M28O5$~$|$~$Amzn.com/billWA$~$|$~$DBT PURCHASE$~$|$~$5942$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00007$~$|$~$35$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$||$~$001$~$||$~$0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0136$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$91.94$~$|$~$8888 $~$|$~$42283$~$|$~$AMZN Mktp US*M26ZY$~$|$~$Amzn.com/billWA$~$|$~$DBT PURCHASE$~$|$~$5942$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00002$~$|$~$35$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$||$~$0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0135$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$57.48$~$|$~$8888 $~$|$~$42285$~$|$~$JOANN STORES #2125$~$|$~$WARWICK      RI$~$|$~$POS DEBIT$~$|$~$5949$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00005$~$|$~$35$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$|$~$|0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0135$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$7.89$~$|$~$8888 $~$|$~$42287$~$|$~$2740 SOUTH KIN$~$|$~$SOUTH KINGSTORI$~$|$~$POS DEBIT$~$|$~$5541$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00006$~$|$~$35$~$
```

In this sample data, there should be 17 fields delimitered with |, there are a few lines with more than 16 |, creating more than 17 fields

Checking the count of fields seems to be the most efficient way to have a quick idea on the raw data, there might be other issues in the data, I will post them later if I do not have the solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: What does "Bad Data" mean here?

Comment: Bad data means lines that are not matching the pattern, the data is in csv file so has its schema, occasionally lines are missing delimiters or have more delimiters (which could create extra fields), they are deemed as bad data.

Comment: I'm always pulled in two directions when I hit this issue. I've generally fallen on the side of scrubbing on the file system, but I generally injest data into a RDBMS and I've not used spark so I'm not sure what it's capabilities are. My ETL tool is pretty rigid so any deviation from the schema causes errors and most the time if I can't get 100% of the data then I want none of it. 99.99% is still wrong. In those cases I generally hit the file with awk. Something like: `awk -F"<delim>" 'BEGIN{fieldcount=50}NF!=fieldcount{print $0>FILENAME"_BAD.csv";next}{print $0}' infile.csv > outfile.csv`

Comment: Thank you very much, can you put sample of good/bad files in an answer, would be very interesting to test it out here and see how can I go from there.

Comment: You could receive much more intelligible answers if you posted an example of good data lines and bad data lines so that an actual regex could be formed to differentiate between the two. You will want an `awk` or `sed` solution, otherwise write a small C program to do it.

Comment: yes, I'll make update to the OP, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: This is counter to what most companies use Hadoop for.  Typically you sanitize data in your ETL pipeline, not out of it.  This is because your raw data is large and requires Hadoop scale while the sanitized and consolidated data is several orders of magnitude smaller.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in my comment, I often use awk for testing for delimiter issues. This can get a little ugly if you have string encapsulation characters as well, but if that isn't an issue then it's pretty simple work:

```
$ cat testfile.csv
a,1,2,3,4,5,6
b,1,2,3,4,5
c,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
d,1,2,3,4,5,6
e,1,2,3,4,5,6

$ awk -F"," 'BEGIN{fieldcount=7}NF!=fieldcount{print $0>FILENAME"_bad";next}{print $0}' testfile.csv > testfile_good.csv

$ cat testfile.csv_bad
b,1,2,3,4,5
c,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

$ cat testfile_good.csv
a,1,2,3,4,5,6
d,1,2,3,4,5,6
e,1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your input, using Miller (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
mlr --nidx --fs "|" put '$nf=NF' then cut -f nf then cat -n input
```

these are number of fields per row

```
1|17
2|17
3|17
4|17
5|19
6|17
7|17
8|18
9|18
10|17
11|19
12|18
13|18
```

If you want only rows with 17 fields

```
mlr --nidx --fs "|" put '$nf=NF' then filter '$nf==17' then cut -x -f nf input
```

gives you

```
$~$TRN_FILE_DT$~$|$~$TRN_BANK_STATE_ID$~$|$~$ACCT_NUM_FULL$~$|$~$TRN_TRANSACTION_CD$~$|$~$TRN_TRANSACTION_DT$~$|$~$TRN_TRANSACTION_AMT$~$|$~$TRN_BAT_NUM$~$|$~$TRN_SEQ_NUM$~$|$~$TRN_LOCUSORTYPE$~$|$~$TRN_CITYST$~$|$~$TRN_PURPOSE$~$|$~$TRN_ATM_LOC_CD$~$|$~$TRN_AMT_LOC_ON_US$~$|$~$TRN_AMT_REMOTE_BR$~$|$~$TRN_ATM_GL_RC$~$|$~$TRN_POST_SEQ$~$|$~$TRN_POSTING_PRIORITY$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$|$~$0xBFACD988EAF6ABE515C16CE33C10F0860B33C83D$~$|$~$0129$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$1425.00$~$|$~$5912 $~$|$~$13312$~$|$~$TO CHECKING$~$|$~$$~$|$~$TO CHECKING$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00001$~$|$~$35$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$|$~$0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0170$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$3503.71$~$|$~$7200 $~$|$~$90542$~$|$~$Morgan Stanley$~$|$~$$~$|$~$ACH CREDIT$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00001$~$|$~$20$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$|$~$0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0136$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$34.00$~$|$~$8888 $~$|$~$51279$~$|$~$Village Nails & Sp$~$|$~$CRANSTON     RI$~$|$~$DBT PURCHASE$~$|$~$7230$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00001$~$|$~$35$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$|$~$0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0136$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$75.19$~$|$~$8888 $~$|$~$66089$~$|$~$P.J.'S PUB$~$|$~$NARRAGANSETT RI$~$|$~$DBT PURCHASE$~$|$~$5812$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00003$~$|$~$35$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$|$~$0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0136$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$9.34$~$|$~$8888 $~$|$~$66093$~$|$~$Amazon.com*M26TD1R$~$|$~$Amzn.com/billWA$~$|$~$DBT PURCHASE$~$|$~$5942$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00004$~$|$~$35$~$
$~$2019-01-01 00:00:00$~$|$~$001$~$|$~$0xDFC9ACE6A089C648E74524847A7273763475655D$~$|$~$0136$~$|$~$2018-12-31 00:00:00$~$|$~$5.92$~$|$~$8888 $~$|$~$66091$~$|$~$AMZN Mktp US*M28O5$~$|$~$Amzn.com/billWA$~$|$~$DBT PURCHASE$~$|$~$5942$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$$~$|$~$00007$~$|$~$35$~$
```